# \providecommand equivalent of \DeclareMathOperator: \ProvideMathOperator?

Tags: amsmath

What is the `\providecommand` equivalent of `\DeclareMathOperator`?

I.e. as `\providecommand` is to `\newcommand` a method for defining new commands if and only if they have not already been defined?

Actually, as pointed out by @egreg in the comments, `\providecommand` can be dangerous since it might adversely affect the behaviour of packages that define it.  What I would really like is something that combines the ability of `\providecommand` to quietly ensure a command exists with the functionality of `\CheckCommand` to make sure that the provided definition is consistent with previous definitions.

Comment: Of course there are lots of ways of doing this, ``\let``ing the previous definition to ``\relax``, or using the equivalent of ``\providecommand{\X}{\mbox{X}}`` for example, but it struck me as odd that there is not something better... Am I missing something?

Comment: Using `\mbox` won't automatically give you the correct spacing around the operator (`\DeclareMathOperator` does this properly).

Comment: I wouldn't rely on such a `\ProvideMathOperator`. Let's say you want to define a "fi" operator. If you say `\ProvideMathOperator{\fi}{fi}` and start using `\fi`, the resulting errors will be puzzling. I'm *very* cautious also with `\providecommand`.

Comment: @egreg I agree: What I am actually looking for is a command like ``\providecommand`` but that emits an error if the definition is not the same. I though I saw something like that before, but I can't recall where I saw it.

Comment: Just a note: looking at the LaTeX3 interface in ``xparse``, ``\DeclareBlah``... defines *without checking*.  Thus, the ``amsmath`` ``\DeclareMathOperator`` behaves as if it were called ``\NewMathOperator``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd be very cautions in using `\providecommand` or variations thereof. This simple example may show why: if you say

```
\providecommand{\box}{something}
```

and then start using `\box` in your document, *very* puzzling error messages will be raised.

One might think to define a `\ProvideMathOperator` that also checks for the definition of the first argument, if already defined somehow, and warns if the control sequence we are trying to define is an operator (with the same definition) or not.

However this is quite hard: the supplied control sequence might have *any* definition, with mandatory or optional arguments, be robust or even be unexpandable.

One could deal with all these variations, in principle, but it's rather hard (I assure you it really is). The number of predefined math operators is not very big, after all, so the "*use `\DeclareMathOperator` and try with another name if LaTeX complains*" way seems to be the less complicated one.

---

Here's a rather simplistic procedure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ProvideMathOperator}{smm}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #2
   {
    \xopn_check:Nn #2 { #3 }
   }
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      { \DeclareMathOperator*{#2}{#3} }
      { \DeclareMathOperator{#2}{#3} }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xopn_check:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { \cs_to_str:N #1\c_space_tl }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_xopn_name_tl { \token_get_replacement_spec:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 \c_space_tl } }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_xopn_name_tl { \token_get_replacement_spec:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 } }
   }
   \xopn_check_operator:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xopn_check_operator:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \regex_match:nVTF { \A \\qopname\ \\(newmcodes@|relax)\ (o|m) \{ #2 \} \Z } \l_xopn_name_tl
    { \msg_warning:nnx { xopn } { samedefinition } { \token_to_str:N #1 } }
    { \msg_warning:nnxx { xopn } { differentdefinition } { \token_to_str:N #1 } { \l_xopn_name_tl } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF {nV}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \token_get_replacement_spec:N {c}
\msg_new:nnn { xopn } { samedefinition }
 {
  The~operator~`#1'~already~exists~with~the~same~definition
 }
\msg_new:nnn { xopn } { differentdefinition }
 {
  The~command~`#1'~has~already~a~different~definition\\
  \\
  #2\\
  \\
  (If~the~above~reads~`\token_to_str:N \scan_stop:'~don't~
  redefine~`#1'~under~any~circumstances,~but~be~cautious~anyway)
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ProvideMathOperator{\log}{log}
\ProvideMathOperator{\gcd}{gcd}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}
\ProvideMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}

\ProvideMathOperator{\null}{null}
\ProvideMathOperator{\fi}{fi}
```

I just try and see whether the proposed control sequence exists or not; in the latter case `\DeclareMathOperator` is safe. In the former case, I look whether the "command with trailing space in the name" exists; then I compare the meaning of the command (using the one with the trailing space, if existent) to what `amsmath` would have defined it if it's an operator.

The output of the document is

```
*************************************************
* xopn warning: "samedefinition"
* 
* The operator `\log' already exists with the same definition
*************************************************
*************************************************
* xopn warning: "samedefinition"
* 
* The operator `\gcd' already exists with the same definition
*************************************************
*************************************************
* xopn warning: "samedefinition"
* 
* The operator `\Tor' already exists with the same definition
*************************************************
*************************************************
* xopn warning: "differentdefinition"
* 
* The command `\null' has already a different definition
* 
* \hbox {}
* 
* (If the above reads `\scan_stop:' don't redefine `\null' under any
* circumstances, but be cautious anyway)
*************************************************
*************************************************
* xopn warning: "differentdefinition"
* 
* The command `\fi' has already a different definition
* 
* \scan_stop: 
* 
* (If the above reads `\scan_stop:' don't redefine `\fi' under any
* circumstances, but be cautious anyway)
*************************************************
```

When the warning is issued, no definition is performed.

`\ProvideMathOperator` accepts the `*`-variant just like `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: As I try to implement a simple solution, I am beginning to appreciate the "rather hard"ness of this problem!

Comment: @mforbes I've added a LaTeX3 solution.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think such a command exists in `amsmath`, but you can create your own using `\ifdefined`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\ProvideMathOperator[2]{\ifdefined#1\else\DeclareMathOperator{#1}{#2}\fi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\goat}{goat}
\ProvideMathOperator{\sheep}{sheep}
\ProvideMathOperator{\goat}{} %Has no effect because \goat is already defined.
\begin{document}
$\goat$ $\sheep$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I understand it, the `\provide`-command would define OR redefine something, based on its existence/not. That is, not just do nothing if it already exists.

Comment: ...see the definition of `\provide@command` in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx).

Comment: @Werner --- I think you are mistaken. I just did a simple test and `\providecommand` did not overwrite an existing definition.

Comment: @Werner `\providecommand` doesn't redefine an already existent command.

Comment: @egreg: True, and strange.

Comment: @Werner That's exactly what `\providecommand` is supposed to do. Let's say you need a command that's provided by a package that you may or may not load (perhaps in a simplified version). You put `\providecommand` in the preamble. But it's important to know what's the syntax of the "emulated" command, or chaos will ensue when you load that package. That's why I'm cautious with it.

Comment: @mforbes That's `\CheckCommand`.

Comment: @egreg: So `\providecommand` doesn't stand for `P`lease `R`edefine `O`r `V`aguely `I`denfitify `D`a `E`xistence of the `COMMAND`? `:)` In all seriousness, I understand the problems that may occur.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I will modify the question to encourage that usage and discourage ``\providecommand``.  (P.S. I moved my question to the question comments... could you please move your answer?)

Comment: @IanThompson: Would you mind if I update your answer to include a ``\CheckCommand`` to emphasize the dangers @egreg mentions?

Comment: @mforbes --- be my guest.

Comment: @egreg: Having a little difficulty using `\CheckCommand` here since `\DeclareMathOperator` emits a robust command.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63670/how-to-use-checkcommand-with-robust-commands.