# How to use \CheckCommand with robust commands?

Tags: macros

### Question

How can I use `\CheckCommand` with robust commands?

### Background

LaTeX provides `\CheckCommand` (only for use in the preamble) so you can ensure that a command has the expected definition:

```
\newcommand{\hi}{hi}
\CheckCommand{\hi}{hi}
```

will work fine without any warnings, but

```
\newcommand{\hi}{hi}
\CheckCommand{\hi}{bonjour}
```

will cause LaTeX to emit a warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \hi  has changed.
           Check if current package is valid.
```

This warning system, however, is thwarted by the LaTeX protection mechanism for robust commands:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hi}{hi}
\CheckCommand{\hi}{hi}
```

raises a warning because `\hi` is now `\protect\hi`, not `hi`. (See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) for example.)

How can I use `\CheckCommand` with robust commands?

### References

- [\providecommand equivalent of \DeclareMathOperator: \ProvideMathOperator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63655/providecommand-equivalent-of-declaremathoperator-providemathoperator)

Comment: You can look at the documentation of `xpatch` or `regexpatch` to see something related to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I introduce a new command `\DefineRobustCommand` in place of LaTeX's `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Why? Well, you can see the reason if you compare the definition of `\DefineRobustCommand` with that of `\DeclareRobustCommand`. `\DeclareRobustCommand` uses a trailing space on the parent command to define a unique auxiliary command, but this is not the issue here. One reason is that `\DeclareRobustCommand` isn't meant for one-letter commands/definitions like

```
\DeclareRobustCommand~[1][]{\def\x{#1}}
```

With

```
\expandafter\@gobble\string#1
```

as seen in the definition of `\DeclareRobustCommand`, auxiliary commands defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand` can't distinguish between command symbols.

If you want to "check" a defined command, use `\DefineRobustCommand` instead of `\DeclareRobustCommand`. You can use `\VerifyCommand` to check all LaTeX-defined commands, except those defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

`\VerifyCommand` will issue a warning if the command doesn't match previous definition, while `\XVerifyCommand` will issue an error in that case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\amtemptoks
\def\iffurcate#1\fi{%
  #1\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}
\def\ifcmddef#1{%
  \iffurcate\ifdefined#1\fi{%
    \iffurcate\ifx#1\relax\fi\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo
  }{%
    \@secondoftwo
  }%
}
\def\ifnamedef#1{\expandafter\ifcmddef\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\DefineRobustCommand{\@star@or@long\define@robustcommand}
\def\define@robustcommand#1{%
  \ifx#1\@undefined\else\ifx#1\relax\else
    \@latex@info{Redefining \string#1}%
  \fi\fi
  \edef\am@tempa{\string#1}%
  \def\am@tempb{#1}%
  \edef\am@tempb{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\am@tempb}%
  \edef#1{%
    \ifx\am@tempa\am@tempb\unexpanded{\am@xprotect#1}\fi
    \noexpand\protect
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#1@RoB\endcsname
  }%
  \let\@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
  \expandafter\new@command\csname\string#1@RoB\endcsname
}
\def\am@xprotect#1#2#3{%
  \iffurcate\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\fi{#3}{\protect#1}%
}
\def\VerifyCommand{\def\am@switch{0}\@star@or@long\am@checkcommand}
\def\XVerifyCommand{\def\am@switch{1}\@star@or@long\am@checkcommand}
\def\am@checkcommand#1#2#{\am@ch@ckcommand#1{#2}}
\long\def\am@ch@ckcommand#1#2#3{%
  \let\am@resa\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname\string\am@resa\endcsname\relax
  \new@command\am@resa#2{#3}%
  \amtemptoks{%
    \ifnamedef{\@backslashchar\string#1@RoB}{%
      \expandafter\let\csname\string\am@resa@RoB\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\let\csname\@backslashchar\string\am@resa@RoB\endcsname\relax
      \define@robustcommand\am@resa#2{#3}%
      \expandafter\am@checkeqcmd
      \csname\@backslashchar\string\am@resa@RoB\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname\@backslashchar\string#1@RoB\endcsname
      #1%
    }{%
      \am@checkeqcmd#1\am@resa#1%
    }%
  }%
  \ifnamedef{\string#1}{%
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{\detokenize{\@protected@testopt}}
      {\expandafter\meaning\csname\string#1\endcsname}%
    \ifin@
      \expandafter\am@checkeqcmd
      \csname\string\am@resa\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname\string#1\endcsname#1%
    \else
      \the\amtemptoks
    \fi
  }{%
    \the\amtemptoks
  }%
}
\def\am@checkeqcmd#1#2#3{%
  \def\am@ch@ckeqcmd{Command \noexpand#3 has changed.
    \MessageBreak Check that there is nothing wrong}%
  \ifx#1#2\else
    \if1\am@switch
      \@latexerr\am@ch@ckeqcmd\@ehd
    \else
      \@latex@warning@no@line\am@ch@ckeqcmd
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Tests
\newcommand\hy{Hi}
\VerifyCommand\hy{Hi}
\XVerifyCommand\hy{Hi}

\newcommand\hiy[2]{Hi #1, #2}
\XVerifyCommand\hiy[2]{Hi #1, #2}
% \XVerifyCommand\hiy{Hi, -changed-}

\DefineRobustCommand\hiz[2][x]{Hi (#1***#2)}
\VerifyCommand\hiz[2][x]{Hi (#1***#2)}
% \VerifyCommand\hiz[2][x]{Hi-changed [#1***#2]}
\XVerifyCommand\hiz[2][x]{Hi (#1***#2)}
% \XVerifyCommand\hiz[2][x]{Hi-changed [#1***#2]}

% \| is defined as a delimiter. Defining | as a robust command 
% will not change that:
\begingroup
\lccode`~=`|
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \DefineRobustCommand~[2][x]{\def\x{#1***#2}}
}
{\catcode`|=13
  \XVerifyCommand|[2][x]{\def\x{#1***#2}}
  % \XVerifyCommand|[2][x]{-changed-\def\x{#1***#2}}
  %|{y}
}
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank Ahmed.  I will have to look a bit more closely at this.  Could you please let me know how this code came to be: is it just a simple hacked modification of the LaTeX internals, or a more sophisticated rewrite?  I was hoping for something a little more "standard", but maybe it is not possible.  Will wait a bit to see if a simpler solution comes up before accepting.

Comment: `\DefineRobustCommand` may qualify as a hack, but not `\VerifyCommand` and `\XVerifyCommand`. What you wanted doesn't exist in the LaTeX kernel. I personally would have preferred eTeX's `\protected` for defining robust commands these days. There are issues with LaTeX's robust commands. For example, they expand under `\edef` or equivalent milieus. LaTeX resorted to `\protect` because there wasn't eTeX in the early days of TeX. You can still access optional arguments with `\protected` if you are familiar with `\@testopt`.

Answer (score 5):

As you probably know by now, `\DeclareRobustCommand{\cs}{...}` defines *two* commands: essentially it does

```
\def\cs{\protect\cs•}
\def\cs•{...}
```

where I denote with `•` a space in the command's name (which is ordinarily not possible). When LaTeX finds this in normal typesetting, `\protect` is equivalent to `\relax`, so the expansion of `\cs•` does that's requested. When LaTeX is writing into auxiliary files, `\protect` is `\noexpand`, so the effect is of writing the string `\cs` followed by a space (when the auxiliary file will be input, that space will not be considered part of the name, but that's irrelevant).

So, in order to check a robust command, you have to look at the expansion of `\cs•`, but you must know in advance whether the command is robust.

The situation is further complicated by the fact that the expansion of `\1` after `\DeclareRobustCommand\1{...}` is

```
\x@protect\1\protect\1•
```

(again • denotest a space in the name).

In the packages `xpatch` and `regexpatch` I do a check on the various possibilities of the replacement text with the macro `\xpatch_main:NN` (`xpatch`) or `\xpatch_main_check:N` (regexpatch). You can see that the list is quite long.

If you *know* that the command has been defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` then

```
\def\CheckRobustCommand#1{%
  \expandafter\CheckCommand\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\space\endcsname
}% (AM)
```

to be used just like `\CheckCommand` might be what you want.

A simple-minded version that only checks whether the "command with a trailing space" is defined can be

```
\makeatletter
\def\CheckRobustCommand#1{%
  \expandafter\CheckCommand\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\space\endcsname
}% (AM)

\def\xCheckCommand#1{%
  \ifcsname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\space\endcsname
    \expandafter\CheckRobustCommand
  \else
   \expandafter\CheckCommand
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

The command `\xCheckCommand` can be used for commands defined by both `\newcommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand`. (AM)

Comment: @AhmedMusa Thanks for spotting the missing braces.