# pgfmathprovidefunction functionality

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am looking for a `\pgfmathprovidefunction` which executes a `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` if the given function is not already
declared and does not report an error if it was already defined (but does not change the existing definition).

My hack below *seems* to work fine if I always use `\pgfmathprovidefunction`, but if an existing function was originally defined with `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` it will fail compilation.

The desired output is

[image]

### References:

- [\tikzset{My Style/.provide style={}}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22640/4301)
- [\provideenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20687/4301)
- [\ProvideMathOperator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63655/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\pgfmathprovidefunction#1#2#3{%
    \ifcsdef{#1 Function Declared}{}{%
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        \csgdef{#1 Function Declared}{}%
    }%
}%

\pgfmathprovidefunction{MyFunction}{1}{%
      \pgfmathparse{0.5*pow(#1,2)}%
}%

\pgfmathprovidefunction{MyFunction}{1}{%
      \pgfmathparse{0.5*pow(#1,3)}%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \draw [ultra thick,blue,latex-latex, domain=-2:2] plot (\x,{MyFunction(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you looking for something like the following? `\makeatletter\def\pgfmathprovidefunction#1#2#3{\ifcsdef{pgfmath@function@#1}{}{\pgfmathdeclarefunction{#1}{#2}{#3}}}\makeatother`

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: Yep, that seems to work. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{F}` macro defines `\pgfmath@function@F`, which can be used to check if a function is already declared:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathprovidefunction#1#2#3{%
    \ifcsdef{pgfmath@function@#1}{}{%
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{MyFunction}{1}{%
      \pgfmathparse{0.5*pow(#1,2)}%
}%

\pgfmathprovidefunction{MyFunction}{1}{%
      \pgfmathparse{0.5*pow(#1,3)}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \draw [ultra thick,blue,latex-latex, domain=-2:2] plot (\x,{MyFunction(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```